How to retrieve release year as meta data of media with QMediaMetaData class in Qt6
In Qt5 it is possible to retrieve information about the year of release from the meta data of a media file with the Key QMediaMetaData::Year. But that key seems to have disappeared in Qt 6.7. There is a key QMediaMetaData::Date, but holds the creation date of the media file.
How can I retrieve the release year as meta data from a media file with Qt 6.7?
I tried to retrieve the value for the QMediaMetaData::Date Key, but always retrieved an invalid QVariant, so I guess that QMediaMetaData::Date is not the right way.
